# Remote Desktop from Window 10 asking for Smart Card service

Tags: remote-desktop, smartcard

I'm trying to connect to my work PC using Remote Desktop from my home, Windows 10 PC. I bring up the Remote Desktop dialog, enter the computer name to connect to, and hit Connect, but receive the error: "The smart card service is not running. Please start the smart card service and try again."

[image: Error message - start service]

If I start the Smart Card service (not trivial, because the service is Disabled and can't be Enabled without modifying the registry), I get a different error: "A smart card reader was not detected. Please attach a smart card reader and try again."

[image: Error message - attach a reader]

This doesn't seem to be anything on the remote end, as it occurs even if I type nonsense for the computer name, and whether or not I have connected to the work VPN.

How do I convince Remote Desktop that it doesn't need a Smart Card?

Comment: Do you use a smart card at work?  Have you asked your Network Administrator about this problem?

Comment: We don't - it's a normal password domain login. Also, as mentioned, I get the error whether or not I'm on the work VPN, or even connecting to a real computer - the error seems to come before the connection is attempted.

Comment: If you go to show options in Remote desktop (that arrow in the bottom left), then tab local resources, then at the bottom press the More... button, and uncheck smart cards, does that fix your issue?

Comment: @LPChip Astonishingly, no. Same symptoms.

Comment: and if you reboot? (not shutdown, then turn on pc, but actuallly reboot? sounds like a service or driver is hanging.

Comment: As it happened, the PC hung yesterday and had to be hardware-button-rebooted. Same problem before and after.

Comment: Find the reason for the disconnect in the RDP event log: 'Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows\Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operational'. Match it up to the codes here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37870.rds-remote-desktop-client-disconnect-codes-and-reasons.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly two years after posting, I've finally resolved this issue. Under "Show options -> Advanced -> Connect from Anywhere Settings", I found that Remote Desktop was still expecting to use the RD Gateway for my old job, which I left 9 years ago. I switched that setting to "Automatically detect RD Gateway settings", and I was able to connect.